# Why is my R.drawable valie is INT? now I cant populate my listview

Tags: bitmap, android-bitmap

I'm having problem inserting image to the Expense_items class, even the getter is having a Bitmap value. However, the image in the drawable have a value of int. Why is that?

```
 enter code heremyList.add(new 
    Expense_items(R.drawable.ic_launcher1,"21341","Transportation Fee"));
```

here is the error 
[image]

Comment: R.drawable returns INT. That is why its value is of INT

Comment: @bub how can I put image then? thanks